# In Webpack5, why my function just be excuted?

Tags: webpack-5

**my file**
//index.js

```js
const path = require("path");



module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "index.js"),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  },
  optimization: {
    usedExports: true,
  }
};
```

// webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require("path");



module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "index.js"),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  },
  optimization: {
    usedExports: true,
  }
};
```

**build result**

```js
(()=>{"use strict";console.log(3)})();
//# sourceMappingURL=main.js.map
```

**in webpack4, the build result is like this,and  why webpack5's just excute my fuction?**

```js
(()=>{"use strict";console.log(1+2)})();
//# sourceMappingURL=main.js.map
```

in webpack5, the build result is like this

```js
(()=>{"use strict";console.log(3)})();
//# sourceMappingURL=main.js.map
```

Comment: So, you're basically complaining that it does constant folding?

Comment: no,  I just wonder why the webpack executed my code, it should have just been built and not built for me and executed my code

Comment: I don't see the problem. And your `my file //index.js` is wrong.

Comment: sorry, my index.js is:  

```js 
"use strict";

export function sum(x, y) {
  return x + y;
}

console.log(sum(1, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you didn't provide your index.js. Second, I believe you wrote something trivial like: `console.log(1+2)` in your index.js. Finally, if you execute your index.js then it should run `console.log(1+2)`. Your bundle.js therefore also run `console.log(1+2)`. I don't see the problem and I see no effort in organizing/double-checking your question. Webpack is such a complicated and bgi project, it's almost impossible to have such a little issue without anyone found it before you. Always try to formulate yrou question clearly before trying to fproove something wrong .

Comment: sorry, my index.js is:  

```js 
"use strict";

export function sum(x, y) {
  return x + y;
}

console.log(sum(1, 2));
```

Comment: I never execute my index.js  its the build result ite self is console.log(3)